# How can we add copy of existing testcase to another testsuite using groovy

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

## Requirement:

I have 2 testcases and will grow in future.  I need a way to run  these 2 testcase in multiple environment parallel at runtime.

So I can either  make multiple copies of these testcase for multiple environment and add them to empty testsuite and set to run them parallel. All these using groovy script.

Or try a way to run each testcase parallel by some code.
I tried `tcase.run(properties,async)`
but did not work.

Need help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful. You are mixing together unrelated things.

1. If you have a non-Pro installation, then you can parameterize the endpoints. This is accomplished by editing all your endpoints with a SoapUI property, and passing these to your test run. This is explained in the [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html#4-example-n-centralized-endpoint).
2. If you have a -Pro license, then you have access to the Environments feature, which essentially wraps the above for you in a convenient manner. Again: consult [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/environment-handling-in-soapui.html).
3. Then a separate question is how to run these in parallel. That will very much depend on what you have available. In the simplest case, you can create a shell script that calls `testrunner` the appropriate number of times with appropriate arguments. [Official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/cli-functional-tests.html) is available. There are also options to run from Maven - [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html) - in which case you can use any kind of CI to run these.
4. I do not understand how Groovy would play into all this, unless you would like to get really fancy and run all this from [junit](/questions/tagged/junit), which also has [official documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html) available.
5. If you need additional information, you could read through SO [official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps clarify your answer.

Comment: Simply I need a way to run my testcases parallel using groovy script.